# Does any compiler support constexpr yet?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to play with `constexpr`, does any compiler support it yet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Apache Stdcxx project has [a nice table detailing which C++0x features are supported by which compilers](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport).  It's been updated on a regular basis and covers most of the modern C++ compilers.

<s>According to that, only GCC 4.5 supports `constexpr` (note that that support may be experimental).</s>

Between that list and what has been said in the comments, it appears the answer is "no."

Comment: The [official GCC support table](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) states that `constexpr` is not supported at all. My code does compile with `constexpr`, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever. My first guess is that the keyword is simply ignored?

Comment: @Fred:  Maybe no one supports it then.  I don't use gcc frequently enough to know much about its C++0x support, sadly.

Comment: Just tested on g++ (GCC) 4.6.0 20100605 -- still can't create an array of size returned by a constexpr function. Reading bugzilla, it appears GCC 4.5 introduced syntax, but not (yet) semantics.

Comment: The released version of GCC4.6 now has `constexpr` support.

Answer (score 4):

As of July 2011, gcc 4.7 supports constexpr. You need to build it from svn though.

Answer (score -2):

Agreed, g++ 4.5 and 4.6 support the keyword, but ignore the implications. I just compiled a simple factorial program (on both versions using -std=c++0x) with the line:

```
constexpr fact(int i) { return (i>1) ? fact(i-1)*i : 1; }
```

and it compiled and ran but when examining the asm source (-S option) it showed the function was called with the parameter instead of being determined by the compiler.

Comment: The answer is useless without showing your test program. Your description sounds like you misunderstood `constexpr` (and the function definition you show isn't valid C++. C++ has no "implicit int").

Answer (score -9):

Usage of "constexpr" is really easy. Look at this piece of code:

```
constexpr int get_five(){
return 5;}
```

This function returns always 5, so it can be declared with "constexpr" keyword. 
But factorial function returns value depending on argument, so its "output" is not always the same.

Comment: `constexpr int factorial(int n) {
    return n == 0? 1 : n * factorial(n-1);
}` is perfectly valid.